# Divide the testing set into subgroup, then make prediction on each subgroup separately

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset similar to the following table: [image]

The prediction target is going to be the 'score' column. I'm wondering how can I divide the testing set into different subgroups such as score between 1 to 3 or then check the accuracy on each subgroup.

Now what I have is as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
model = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
for i in (0,1,2,3,4):
    y_new=y_test[(y_test>=i) & (y_test<=i+1)]
    y_new_pred=model.predict(X_test)
    print metrics.r2_score(y_new, y_new_pred)
```

However, my code did not work and this is the traceback that I get:

> Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [14279,
>   55955]

I have tried the solution provided below, but it looks like that for the full score range (0-5) the r^2 is 0.67. but the subscore range for example (0-1,1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5) the r^2s are significantly lower than that of the full range. shouldn't some of the subscore r^2 be higher than 0.67 and some of them be lower than 0.67?

Could anyone kindly let me know where did I do wrong? Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: I think you you're looking for `confusion matrix`. Just create the groups of output variable before passing it to function. That should work.

Comment: Obviously, while `y_new_pred` contains the predictions for the whole of your test set `X_test` (55955 samples), `y_new` contains only a subset (14279) of the true labels, so any metric calculation (`r2_score` or otherwise) is doomed to fail, hence the error; see the answer below (and kindly accept it, since it arguably resolves your issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are computing the metrics, you have to filtered the predicted values (based on your subset condition).

Basically you are trying to compute

```
metrics.r2_score([1,3],[1,2,3,4,5])
```

which creates an error,

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [2, 5]

Hence, my suggested solution would be

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
#compute the prediction only once. 
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

for i in (0,1,2,3,4):
    #COMPUTE THE CONDITION FOR SUBSET HERE
    subset = (y_test>=i) & (y_test<=i+1)
    print metrics.r2_score(y_test [subset], y_pred[subset])
```

Comment: `Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 55955)) while a minimum of 1 is required.`  Thank you for your help my friend but after applying your solution I got the above traceback. Any idea why this is happening、

Comment: by the way I printed out `y_test [subset]` and `y_pred[subset]` they are both empty

Comment: Ok my friend. I did something wrong when applying your code. I studied your solution step by step. so the subset only has True and False value. So the `y_test [subset] and y_pred[subset]` will only keep the items that is labeled true in subset. Is my understanding correct？

Comment: @ AI_Learning I have some questions regarding your solution my friend, but it looks like that for the full score range (0-5) the r^2 is 0.67. but the subscore range for example (0-1,1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5) the r^2s are significantly lower than that of the full range. shouldn't some of the subscore r^2 be higher than 0.67 and some of them be lower than 0.67?. Thanks a lot for your help